# android studio: How to programmatically change an adjacent TextView on the same tablerow?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It's an inventory count app...that loads the quantity of items on the inventory database and the inventory auditor has to enter the counted quantity for each item and the app will tell them whether it's correct.:
1) the app receives a JSON string from the server containing a list of items and their stock quantity..it's loaded into an array named "jArray"
2) from this Array, the UI display each item in a new row:
col 1: item description, 
col 2: edittext field for user input of counted quantity, 
col 3: a hidden (white text in white bg) field containing the correct quantity..
3) if the entered qty does not match the text in col 3, then it will chg the col3 textview color to red as a warning...

issue is, how do i reference/check the value on the adjacent programmatically created textview on the same tablerow and also change its text color?

 on an html website with javascript, it's just a matter of referencing the 3rd column childnode under the same parentnode ...but what is the equivalent in android/java..or is there an easier way to do this?

thx

```
                for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Pulling items from the array
                        item = oneObject.getString("item");
                        qty = oneObject.getString("qty");

                       // textview on column 1 containing item descr
                        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
                        TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
                        t1v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));
                        t1v.setText(item);
                        tbrow.addView(t1v);

                        // Add edit text field for qty input
                        EditText t4v = new EditText(this);
                        t4v.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                        t4v.setLayoutParams(new  TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));
                        tbrow.addView(t4v);
                        t4v.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence https://stackoverflow.com/editing-helpcharSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                      int before, int count) {
                             // after input from android keypad, check whether the number matches with qty in adjacent textview, if not matching, change adjacent textview color to red 
                                if(s != ***value in adjacent textview *****) {
                                    t5v.setTextColor(Color.RED);}
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        // Add invisible textview (text in white) holding actual quantity of item
                        TextView t5v = new TextView(this);
                        t5v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));
                        t5v.setText(qty);
                        t5v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a tag on the `TextView` when adding it to the table row by using `View.setTag(Object)`. For example use some

```
private static final String QUANTITY_VIEW = "quantity";
```

and write

```
t5v.setTag(QUANTITY_TAG);
tbrow.add(t5v);
```

Then you can retrieve it by writing

```
TextView textView = (TextView) tbrow.findViewWithTag(QUANTITY_TAG);
```

See also the docs for [View.findViewWithTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

You can reference any view by assigning it a custom id, and then pulling it via that ID from its parent.

Example:

```
// r.id.rootlayout is just an arbitrary ID. Replace rootlayout with whatever the ID is of your parent view
ViewGroup parent = findViewById(r.id.rootlayout);

// viewToBeEditedID is the ID of the view you wish to edit. This can be found in any number of ways, but you will be best to track it since it seems that this is dynamically being done.     
TextView viewToBeEdited = (TextView) parent.findViewById(viewToBeEditedID);

// Updated Text is whatever you wish to display.
viewToBeEdited.setText(updatedText);

// Invalidate will tell the parent to "refresh" and show any changes made. Not always necessary, but good practice
parent.invalidate();
```

The trick will be to figure out a clever method of keeping track of your view ID's without being able to actually know them.